# Stanford NLP caseless models via maven

Tags: stanford-nlp

Are the caseless models available via maven? If so, how? Are they just for English? I've tried various options, including:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>${corenlp.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>${corenlp.version}</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>${corenlp.version}</version>
    <classifier>models-caseless</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at this time the caseless models are not in Maven.  I will note your request and I'll see if we can get the caseless models into future Maven releases.

Comment: For 3.6.0, if you set the classifier to "models-english" you'll get the English models jar which has the caseless models in it.  Warning:  it is a large download!